# Is there benefit in playing at higher difficulty levels?

Tags: earth-defense-force-4.1

Does the difficulty level increase armor or weapon drop rate? Are there other rewards? Apparently at least some of the missions add new enemies at higher difficulties which, logically speaking, should affect loot drops.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely get higher level weapon drops.

A friend and I grinded weapons on the first level at a higher difficulty, and our weapons received were on average about level 22 or so. It's a nice way to get weapons for late game while only having to fight giant ants (giant ants with ridiculous amounts of hp, but still not too dangerous).

I didn't particularly notice a higher drop rate or different enemies, but then again I think we were only playing on hard, not on Inferno or anything.

Comment: You can add [this guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps4/730579-earth-defense-force-41-the-shadow-of-new-despair/faqs/72679) to your answer, for instance the estimated weapon drop level for the first mission: "Easy: 0 Normal: 0 Hard: 9-25 Hardest: 0-45 Inferno: 0-50".